# jquery functions overlapping

Tags: jquery

I'm coding a simple sliding images. it's 2 images. image 2 is over image 1 and image 2 is a transparent image. on mouseover event image2 fadein an image url that is in the data of an element. and when it's complete, image 1 source changes to image 2 source and this happens for every mouse over on elements. but the problem is I write a mouseleave event for changeing the source of image 1 when mouse leaves menubar. the code in mouseover rewrite the image 1 source. I don't know why it happens or why leaving the menu area trigger mouseover function.
here is the code:

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.menubar', function() {
  var ID = $(this).attr('data-image');

  if ($('#slides').attr('src') != ID) {
    $('#slides').fadeOut(10, function() {
      //alert($(this).attr('src'));

      $(this).attr('src', ID).bind('onreadystatechange load', function() {
        if (this.complete) $(this).fadeIn(500, function() {

          if (this.complete) {
            $("#slides3").attr("src", ID);

          }

        });
      });
    });
  }
});

$(document).on('mouseleave', '.navx', function() {

  $("#slides").attr("src", 'images/trans.png');
  $('#slides3').attr('src', "images/1-new.png");

});
```

and this is html code:

```
<ul class="navx">
  <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">


    <div class="activex dropdown menubar" data-image="images/1-new.png"><button class="dropbtn" id="menubutton" data-link="#">menu1</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">submenu1</a>
        <a href="#">submenu2</a>
        <a href="#">submenu3 </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class=" singlemenu  menubar" data-image="images/2-new.png">menu2</a>
    <div class=" dropdown menubar" data-image="images/3-new.png">
      <button class="dropbtn" id="menubutton" data-link="#">menu3</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">submenu1 </a>
        <a href="#">submenu2</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class=" singlemenu  menubar" data-image="images/4-new.png">menu4</a>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is something I'm missing here but... Why do you 'mouseover' on '.menubar' but you 'mouseleave' on '.navx'?

You also have four elements with a 'menubar' class there. I think you are probably overlapping your JS actions.

Comment: i just want when user totaly came out from menu it changes to default image. if i set it on '.menubar' every time user move from one menu button to other menu button it blinks. when user is in navx aria it just switch image that assigned to each menu button and when it leaves the navigaion space , image change to default

Comment: about your second question i must say that i want if user mouseover on each menubar it shows different image and each menubar class contain "data-image" with different image url